# Fetch multiple values from firebase database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-asynctask

In our database structure, each "User" holds multiple bid-Ids, each bid-Id represents an entry point in the "Jobs" database.
Currently when we want to iterate through all jobs of a single person the code looks something similar to:

```
final DatabaseReference mDatabaseJobs = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Jobs");
        DatabaseReference mDatabaseUser = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(currentUser.getUid());
        mDatabaseUser.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                DataSnapshot userBids = dataSnapshot.child("listOfBids");
                final int num_user_bids = (int) userBids.getChildrenCount();

                for(final DataSnapshot job : userBids.getChildren()){
                    String jobId = job.getValue(String.class);
                    mDatabaseJobs.child(jobId).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            bid_count.addAndGet(1);
```

Here is the database structure, the objective is somehow to get all the jobs of a specific person.

[image]

Is there a way to retrieve all the jobs at once? mabye a list of keys? and not calling the add-listener for each one?
If not, I know that firebase fetches the data asynchronously, but does it do it in parallel? 
i.e we currently increment an atomic integer to know whether firebase has already fetched all the jobs, because we don't want to threads to increment the counter at the same time, is it necessary in our current implementation?
Thanks!

Comment: Please add your database structure and indicate the exact data taht you want to get.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep a HashMap outside the "Users", populate it with current user's list of jobs. Then attach another listener to "Jobs" and iterate over your hashMap and grab the specific jobs you want. Below is a reference code:

```
HashMap<Integer, String> listOfJobs = new HashMap<>();
DatabaseReference mDatabaseUser = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(currentUser.getUid()).child("listOfBids");

mDatabaseUser.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    if (dataSnapshot.exists) {
        listOfJobs.putAll((Map) dataSnapshot.getValue());
    }
    // Here you can add a listener to the entire "Jobs" reference like this
    DatabaseReference mDatabaseJobs = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Jobs");
    mDatabaseJobs.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot userDataSnapshot) {
            if (userDataSnapshot.exists) {
                for (String jobId : listOfJobs.values()) {
                    if (userDataSnapshot.hasChild(jobId) {
                        DataSnapshot job = userSnapshot.child(jobId);
                        // here you can use job snapshot
                        bid_count.addAndGet(1); // something like this?
                    }
                }
            }
        }

});
```

Basically, you are adding a listener to something that is not nested or deep and using the loop to get the children, instead of adding a listener to nested children.

Hope this helps.

Comment: aren't you fetching the whole jobs database just for a single user query? that sounds expensive, not?

Comment: I don't think it's expensive. Firebase is a NoSQL based Realtime database. It is powerful enough to handle what you're trying to do. You cannot write queries and extract parts of your database. You can try restructuring your database if you want.

Comment: correct me if i'm wrong, but the line mDatabaseUser.addListenerForSingleValueEvent will fetch the whole jobs database to the client phone, no matter how firebase is efficient

Comment: @DsCpp yes, that pulls all the data locally and I don't think it's expensive. If your data in "Jobs" is too much, you can pull a limit amount by adding `.limitToFirst(1000)` or `.limitToLast(500)`